# Stripe card element stopped working and can't seems to know what wrong about it

Tags: javascript, python, django, stripe-payments

HTML file

```
<div class="new-card-form">
    <form action="." method="post" class="stripe-form" id="stripe-form">
        % csrf_token %}
        <div class="stripe-form-row" id="creditCard">
        <label for="card-element" id="stripeBtnLabel">Credit or debit card</label>
        <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
        <div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border:                        none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative    !important; opacity: 1 !important;">
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame5"allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-19066928f2ed1ba3ffada645e45f5b50.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;keyMode=test&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; height: 19.2px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div></div></div>
       <div class="stripe-form-row">
       <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button>
       </div>
                              <div class="stripe-form-row">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="save" id="save_card_info">
                                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="save_card_info">Save for future purchases</label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                          </form>
                          </div>
```

Views.py

```
def post(self,*args, **kwargs):
        # Create Stripe payment
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        chargeID = stripe_payment(settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,token, order.get_total(),str(order.id))

        if (chargeID is not None):
            order.ordered = True

            # create and Save the payment
            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = chargeID
            payment.user = self.request.user 
            payment.price = order.get_total() + 3
            payment.save()

            #assign payment to the order
            order_items = order.items.all()
            order_items.update(ordered=True)
            for item in order_items:
                item.save()
            
            order.ordered = True
            order.payment = payment
            order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
            order.save()
            messages.success(self.request, "payment successful!")
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.warning(self.request, "Something went wrong with Stripe. Please try again later")
            return redirect ('estores:payment', payment_option= 'S')
```

stripe_payment.py

```
import stripe

def stripe_payment (secret_key, token, amount, description ):
    try:
        print(secret_key, token, amount, description, )
        # Use Stripe's library to make requests...
        stripe.api_key = secret_key
        # Token is created using Stripe Checkout or Elements!
        # Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount= int (amount * 100),
            currency='usd',
            description=description,
            source=token,
        )
        return charge['id']
    except stripe.error.CardError as e:
        # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught

        print('Status is: %s' % e.http_status)
        print('Code is: %s' % e.code)
        # param is '' in this case
        print('Param is: %s' % e.param)
        print('Message is: %s' % e.user_message)
    except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
        print (e)
    except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
        print (e)
  
    except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
        # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
        # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
        print (e)

    except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
        # Network communication with Stripe failed
        print (e)

    except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
        # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
        # yourself an email
        print (e)

    except Exception as e:
        # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        print (e)

    return None
```

Js

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script nonce="">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('{{STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}}');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        console.log("tokens not created");
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();}
```

I try to attach a create payment for a user with stripe. It worked for a while then it stopped working and when i tried it returns access denied or error 404 not found.
AccessDeniedAccess DeniedH3KCW9QJT7C1G32GRaEuNCdHBeHbtZAzCJabzmZVuA0uJX/rPfjXt6LZqJRolPP5PO5vn7fZed+8yoq4tU3wZ51KnKI=

console issue:
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ():
[https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-19066928f2ed1ba3ffada645e45f5b50.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&style[base][fontSize]=16px&style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&componentName=card&wait=false&rtl=false&keyMode=test&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&controllerId=__privateStripeController1](https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-19066928f2ed1ba3ffada645e45f5b50.html#style%5Bbase%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%2332325d&style%5Bbase%5D%5BfontFamily%5D=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&style%5Bbase%5D%5BfontSmoothing%5D=antialiased&style%5Bbase%5D%5BfontSize%5D=16px&style%5Bbase%5D%5B::placeholder%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23aab7c4&style%5Binvalid%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23fa755a&style%5Binvalid%5D%5BiconColor%5D=%23fa755a&componentName=card&wait=false&rtl=false&keyMode=test&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&controllerId=__privateStripeController1)

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? What specific part of your code is throwing that 404 error? Have you looked at your requests to Stripe's API to confirm those are going through?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  It would help a lot if you showed us the full error traceback message.

Comment: _it returns access denied or error 404 not found_ That shouldn't be possible, assuming the same url...

Comment: failed to load: server responded with code 404 ():  https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-19066928f2ed1ba3ffada645e45f5b50.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&style[base][fontSize]=16px&style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&componentName=card&wait=false&rtl=false&keyMode=test&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js&controllerId=__privateStripeController1

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: the frontend code is the code causing the problem. thanks fam